# Trying to Update padding-top of a <div> with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a `<div>` that I'm getting the height of, then I want to add 20 pixels to that value to set the `padding-top` of another `<div>`.

```
    <div id="system_message" class="lom_system_message_header">
        <span style="font-size: 24px">SYSTEM ANNOUNCEMENT</span>
        <br>
        Blackboard is currently down.  We\'re working on it.
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var message_height = $("#system_message").height();
        var padding = message_height + 20 + "px";
        alert(padding);         
        $("#system_message_spacer").css("padding-top", padding);
    </script>

    <div id="system_message_spacer"></div>
```

It's not working, but the `alert()` shows as "82px".  When I try `$("#system_message_spacer").css("padding-top", "82px");` in the Chrome dev. tools it works fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to show a **complete and minimal** example that shows the problem. [mcve]

Comment: can you please share your code snippet or fiddle

Comment: Can not reproduce this. I created this codepen. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BwqKZO

Comment: Verified your code and it working fine i.e. added padding-top to the div.

Comment: @DhavalPankhaniya It is required to post the code here, not a third party service. That will only get this question closed quicker.

Comment: I've updated the post with more complete code.

Comment: Your div `system_message_spacer` is after the `<script>` tag. So JS doesn't know the element. Either put the div before `<script>` or move `<script>` after last div. Or, put JS code in jQuery on ready `$(function() { <your code here> });`

Comment: And **this** is why a **complete but minimal example of the code** is required on such questions. Some may be shocked at how often people argue with me about this.

Comment: Doing `$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#system_message_spacer").css("padding-top", padding);
   });` did it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `<script>` tag below the element, right now it will not be present when you try to target it. Alternatively, add this to your existing code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#system_message_spacer").css("padding-top", padding);
});
```